# "Universal Metadata" tagging for various file types

Tags: windows-7, linux, macos, metadata, tags

I'm trying to find some application that allows me to easily add/modify metadata for various files such as PDF, MKV, DOCX, MP3, PNG, JPG etc.

All these types of files (and a lot more) support metadata natively, so metadata can be added and then searched using various programs across various platforms. Of course I've found a myriad of programs that will modify graphics and music files but nothing that also allows me to edit say PDF or DOC files – I have to us a specific PDF or DOC program to update those types of files.

I don't want to use something like Google Desktop (reliant on a central database it makes) or some Windows/Mac only filesystem tagging.

I had thought [Benubird](http://www.debenu.com/benubird/overview.php) might be the answer but that doesn't seem to do it (they said they were working on it but that was 3 years ago I think).

Comment: Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

**[Extensible Metadata Platform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform)**, an initiative by Adobe, abbreviated as XMP.

XMP standardizes a metadata format based on XML and [RDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework). The data can be serialized *into* the actual files such as PDFs, JPEG images, MP3s, MP4s, etc.. Those file types that don't support native embedding can be annotated by just creating an `.xmp` file with the same name.

The Wikipedia article lists [a number of tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform#Various_XMP_tools_.28read.2Fwrite_support.29) that provide read and write support for XMP, for all major platforms.

Answer (score 1):

I am the self-promoting author and creator of [Tape](https://github.com/themanyone/tape), a free and open-source software project to address an imagined need for open, universal, and unrestricted metadata, across platforms, using whatever format we choose.

`Tape` is, optionally, an archive format. And LZMA, `xz` compression is available, if desired. You may attach compressed metadata to files, or keep them uncompressed, or separate. Even create "playable" archives that existing media players will play. It is all up to you. Think of it as another way to tape files together.

To create "playable archives," just use the same file extension. Media players will treat it as an octet stream and quit when they encounter extraneous data (tape metadata, in our case). The data in file, `pe.mp3` could be voice metadata, in `.mp3` format for the visually-impaired. You see, `tape` imposes *zero* restrictions on content, or the format of the chosen metadata we splice onto a file. We could even attach a database file...

```
tape t.mp3 a.mp3 pe.mp3 tape.mp3
```

Tape archives may be extracted in the usual way. More examples are on Github.

```
tape -k tape.mp3
```

If there are bug reports (none, so far), please use the "issues" tab from within Github, fork it, and create a pull request with submitted changes.